# whether it holds $f' \leq f$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f'(x)$ is continuous, and that $f'(x)\geq 0$ and it is increasing for all sufficiently large $x$. Furthermore $f'(x)\leq x^{100}$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Is it true that $f'(x)\leq f(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$?

(It is clear when $f'$ is bounded. Any counterexample for unbounded $f'$?)

Comment: Intuitively, all curves below $f(x)=e^x$ will satisfy such property and all curves above $f(x)=e^x$ will have the opposite property. As $f(x)\leq {x^{101}\over101}<e^x$ this result is true but I am not really sure how a rigorous proof might look like for the intuition.

Comment: Yes, I think it should hold for $f$ up to $e^x$, but I have no idea how to prove it either...

Comment: If $f$ is bounded below $e^x$, then it may not be the case $f'$ is bounded. All we need is for $f'$ to be very small for a very long time and shoot up occasionally.

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant $f'$ up to $e^x$...